# MongoDB cursor results in log file anomaly

Tags: mongodb

I am investigating a problem where our MongoDB performace, degrades hideously when I restart the database computer, I'm guessing because the memory mapped files are gone. One thing I found extremely puzzling in my log file was the following (versions of which are repeated many times)

2015-01-14T13:18:59.404-0600 [conn565] query Analitiqa.ScanInfo query: { query: { Node: -6277503169757883360, StartTime: { $gte: new Date(1418882340000) }, EndTime: { $lte: new Date(1421301660000) } }, $hint: { Node: 1, StartTime: 1, EndTime: -1 } } planSummary: IXSCAN { Node: 1, StartTime: 1, EndTime: -1 } cursorid:167701167819 ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:102 nscannedObjects:101 keyUpdates:0 numYields:97 locks(micros) r:152012 **nreturned:101** reslen:243838 3997ms

2015-01-14T13:20:04.819-0600 [conn565] getmore Analitiqa.ScanInfo cursorid:167701167819 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1500 locks(micros) r:4469422 **nreturned:1690** reslen:4195825 65415ms

2015-01-14T13:20:23.383-0600 [conn565] getmore Analitiqa.ScanInfo cursorid:167701167819 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:390 locks(micros) r:366679 **nreturned:456** reslen:1151794 18489ms
2015-01-14T13:20:23.618-0600 [conn565] end connection 127.0.0.1:51230 (15 connections now open)

My reading of the first line is that the query used the correct index, and is returning 101 results (after an unconscionable delay). The next two lines floor me. They appear to indicate that the cursor gotten from the query returns first 1690, and then 456 items, both after enormous delays.

How is that possible if the query was (correctly) returning only 101 results?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question enough to make an attempt at an answer, but it could be explained by the following quote: "For most queries, the first batch returns 101 documents or just enough documents to exceed 1 megabyte. Subsequent batch size is 4 megabytes." (from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I had the bad luck that I expected around 100 results, so I didn't question the first line. Your explanation is consistent with the problem being a corrupt index. That leaves me with the question with why the index gets consistently corrupt when I restert the (Windows) machine, but I will continue to investigate

Comment: How is it consistent with a corrupt index? To me, it looks like someone is iterating a cursor for a slow query. It's properly indexed, but still slow probably because it's reading every doc it's returning from disk, doing lots of random I/O, just as the server is coming up with nothing cached for mongod or the filesystem. It's pretty ridiculously slow. Is there i/o copntention at the time?